# Connect Xamarin on Mac using Visual Studio

Tags: macos, visual-studio, xamarin

I'm trying connect Xamarin on Mac using Visual Studio. The Mac appears on Xamarin User Agent, but when trying to connect i get this message:

> Starting Broker 4.0.1.96 in port 51743...
>   Couldn't connect to macbook-ricardo.local. Please try again.
>   Disconnected from Mac macbook-ricardo.local (172.19.2.222)
>   bash: /Users/ricardo.lima/Library/Caches/Xamarin/XMA/Broker/4.0.1.96/Broker.exe: cannot execute binary file

The Mac is enabled to receive remote connection for ricardo.lima

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you looked through our troubleshooting guide? https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/windows/connecting-to-mac/troubleshooting/

Comment: Be sure to set up your Mac with the required Xamarin components before attempting to connect from Visual Studio: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/windows/

Comment: Why not take a look at the logs. You can find them in the visual studio help menu under Xamarin. They are quite comprehensive and often very helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure both are on the same version of Xamarin. If you have any trouble take a look at the Connection Troubleshooting: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/windows/connecting-to-mac/troubleshooting/